# Disable one input if another input has value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a jquery table.

I need to disable one input box if the other input box has value, and vice versa.

Here are two input boxes

```
<input type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='0.00' class="form-control">
<input type="text" name='mail0' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" >
```

Comment: [read how to ask a good question on STACK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Going by the data you have provided you can achieve this by using change event of textbox.

```
$('input[name=name0]').on('change', function() {
    if(this.value.length > 0)
       $('input[name=mail0]').attr('disabled','disabled');
    else
       $('input[name=mail0]').removeAttr('disabled');
});


$('input[name=mail0]').on('change', function() {
    if(this.value.length > 0)
       $('input[name=name0]').attr('disabled','disabled');
    else
       $('input[name=name0]').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not disabling with the code provided. Does it matter where I put this code? I added this in a script tag after my table tag closes.

Comment: Yes you have to place this code in `$(document).ready(function(){ //all code });`

Comment: This still doesn't work, do you think it has something to do with the table?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```js
$(function(){
$("input[name=name0]").on('change',function(e){
     $("input[name=mail0]").prop('disabled',$(this).val().length>0);
});
$("input[name=mail0]").on('change',function(e){
        $("input[name=name0]").prop('disabled',$(this).val().length>0);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='0.00' class="form-control"/>
<input type="text" name='mail0' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control"/>
```